# How do get exit code from Ruby's Process.fork()?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, macos, fork

As it says on the tin

```
pid = Process.fork do
  exit 25
end
```

`pid` seems positively useless besides telling me what actual system process number the fork ran under. Will `Thread` be more useful?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the manual for [`fork`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process.html#method-c-fork):

The parent process should use [`Process.wait`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process.html#method-c-wait) to collect the termination statuses of its children or use `Process.detach` to register disinterest in their status; otherwise, the operating system may accumulate zombie processes.

So in your case:

```rb
Process.wait(pid).exitstatus
```

Threads are a completely different thing than a multi-process model. If you're writing parallel code you'll need to determine what your best approach is.

Comment: Down voted because the answer is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

@tadman's answer is incorrect.

`Process::wait` returns pid instead of status, see https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Process.html#wait-method

> Waits for a child process to exit, returns its process id, and sets $? to a Process::Status object containing information on that process.

In your case:

```rb
pid = fork{exit 25} #=> 98287
Process.wait(pid)   #=> 98287
$?.class            #=> Process::Status
$?.exitstatus       #=> 25
$?.to_i             #=> 98287
$?.stopped?         #=> false
$?.exited?          #=> true
```

With thread:

```rb
pid = fork{ exit 123 }
thread = Process.detach(pid)
thread.join.value            #=> #<Process::Status: pid 99172 exit 123>
thread.join.value.exitstatus #=> 123
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
Process.wait(pid)
exit_code = $?.exitstatus
puts exit_code
```